# Animation Nodes viewshed or visibility

Tags: animation-nodes

Is there a way of using Animation nodes to get the visibility from the camera of objects? Not the fustrum, that works great, but what in landscapes is called the viewshed. Wich objects are visible from the camera and which ones are ocluded by other objects or by themselves.
I cant find how to meke this. I have several add ons that can calculate this for weigths, but is there a way to make this with animation nodes?
thanks

Comment: Animation Nodes has a raycast function that is helpful in this regard.  Cast from camera toward object, and if object is the first thing it hits, it's visible.

However, calculating vertex/edge/face/object occlusion in a complex mesh is a non-trivial problem.  Some folks (self included) have done work in this area using Animation Nodes.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100606/animation-nodes-for-geometry-line-art/113985 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87754/ray-cast-function-not-able-to-select-all-the-vertices-in-camera-view/111680 for more info.

Comment: Thank you @zippy , I will take a look at the links