# List of objects in appear in camera view (with script)

Tags: scripting, objects, camera

I would like to list the objects in front of the camera (What will be rendered). I'm thinking about the ray trace detection but maybe there are a better way. 
There is exactly one element listed int the attached image because camera clipping and FOV. So the list will be depend from the camera settings.
I think this is extracted from Blender DATA but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: Close to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/how-to-get-the-3d-coordinates-of-the-visible-vertices-in-a-rendered-image-in-ble/77747#77747

Comment: Very similar to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/how-to-find-all-objects-in-the-cameras-view-with-python