# How to get 2d pixel coordinates of multiple objects bounding boxes from rendered image with python in blender 2.8?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, coordinates, 2d

I know there're many questions similar to mine, but they are a bit too old and not working with newest version of blender.

I found this two, but have no idea how to use them:

```
bge.types.KX_Camera.getScreenPosition
```

[freestyle.utils.bounding_box(stroke)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/freestyle.utils.html?highlight=bounding%20box#freestyle.utils.bounding_box)

And I guess it does what I need, but I can't figure out how to use it. I'm bad with python, and scripting.

I have a scene with a terrain and plants on it. I need to get 2d pixel coordinates of every plant. From top corner to bottom corner, to make a rectangle shape box of every leaf ([similar to this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/save-the-2d-bounding-box-of-an-object-in-rendered-image-to-a-text-file?rq=1), I guess, but maybe I'm wrong).

I have a terrain with plants:
[image]
And I want to get coordinates of every leaf object in json format, to make my software automatically detect position of a leaf object on the picture, when I load a picture and json data into it.
So it would look similar to this, once finished:
[image]
Any ideas on how to make it work? At least I would like to know how to get 2d pixel coordinates of multiple objects from rendered image with python? Or is it possible to get 2d coordinates(from top corner to bottom corner) of bounding boxes of every object?

Here's what I've figured out so far, using a default cube with default position and scale:

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

scene = bpy.context.scene

# needed to rescale 2d coordinates
render = scene.render
res_x = render.resolution_x
res_y = render.resolution_y

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']

# use generator expressions () or list comprehensions []
verts = (vert.co for vert in obj.data.vertices)
coords_2d = [world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, coord) for coord in verts]

# 2d data printout:
rnd = lambda i: round(i)

print('x,y')
for x, y, distance_to_lens in coords_2d:
    print("{},{}".format(rnd(res_x*x), rnd(res_y*y)))
```

Console output:

```
x,y
1308,772
1281,345
946,631
947,166
967,890
967,498
611,779
637,354
```

**Now what's left is to find object's bounding box minimum & maximum x,y  2d coordinates and how to get them?**

```
      # bbox vertices 3d xyz location
        obj = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
        obj.bound_box

        [v[:] for v in obj.bound_box]

    output:

    [(-0.9999998211860657, -1.0000003576278687, -1.0),
     (-0.9999998211860657, -1.0000003576278687, 1.0), 
(-0.9999998211860657, 1.0, 1.0), 
(-0.9999998211860657, 1.0, -1.0), 
(1.000000238418579, -1.0000003576278687, -1.0), 
(1.000000238418579, -1.0000003576278687, 1.0), 
(1.000000238418579, 1.0, 1.0), 
(1.000000238418579, 1.0, -1.0)]
```

**How to convert those 3d coords to 2d world_to_camera_view x,y coords?**

Comment: The script still works if you change the `to_mesh` call according to: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh

Comment: I've tried it, It doesn't @brockmann
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 139, in <module>
  File "/Text", line 135, in main
  File "/Text", line 121, in write_bounds_2d
  File "/Text", line 102, in camera_view_bounds_2d
RuntimeError: Error: Mesh 'Cube' is outside of main database and can not be removed from it
```

Comment: according to my question is it possible to get 2d pixel coordinates(from top corner to bottom corner) of bounding boxes of every object? that could work I guess @brockmann

Comment: Sure, just make the script work @cxnt1

Comment: How to make bounding boxes appear in rendered image?@brockmann

Comment: Also if you could help me fix this script for me, I'd be very grateful, I'm not good with scripting at all @brockmann

Comment: How about creating a the box and adding a wireframe modifier? @cxnt1

Comment: @brockmann how to add a wireframe modifier? I guess, I could just get coordinates of bounding boxes of every object using this ```freestyle.utils.bounding_box(stroke)```(https://docs.blender.org/api/current/freestyle.utils.html?highlight=bounding%20box#freestyle.utils.bounding_box) but not 100% sure what it does. Could it work?

Comment: Hi. If you have additional information please add it to the main body of the question, such as error messages or information addressing comments.

Comment: That can be done using https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.object_utils.html#bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html. From that just loop over the wanted objects, calculate their boundings and use the gpu apis to draw the rectangles. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZqAg.jpg

Comment: @lemon THANKS!! that's exactly, what I was looking for. Could you please show me an example of how to use this please??

Comment: Sure there is an example here about world_to_camera view https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/how-to-get-the-3d-coordinates-of-the-visible-vertices-in-a-rendered-image-in-ble/77747#77747 and many examples about gpu in the doc here https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

Comment: @lemon, will take a look, much appreciated

Comment: @lemon how did you achieve this result as shown on your pic?

Comment: + note: the final image is obtained mixing the generated bounding drawings with gpu and the render result using the compositor.

Comment: @lemon could you please post an answer with script or instruction on how to achieve result as on your pic? I'm having a hard time understanding it

Comment: @lemon how to mix gpu and render result in compositor?

Comment: @cxnt1, in this case with a alpha over node.

Comment: @lemon and what gpu settings did u use?

Comment: This is not gpu settings, this is gpu api that allow to draw the rectangles on an image (see here, many examples about it https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html) so that it can be mixed with the rendering (whatever engine or engine settings you are using) using the alpha over node.

Comment: @lemon which example did u use? 2d rectangle example is something different as I can see

Comment: I don't know, never used freestyle apis. But you should try something because we can not extend this discussion so much here. Try something and come back with precise questions, please.

Comment: @lemon I mean whenever I try and apply some of the gpu's api examples, they doesnt appear in rendered result

Comment: You can use offscreen render then draw using 2D built in shader then retrieve the gl image buffer so that you can copy it into a blender image. Alternatively you can use bgl module, but specs have changed recently and am not sure of what to use for now (something to check, though)